# Cellrenderer and react-router-dom Link

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

This question is duplicated.
But the old one is not answered
I need to use React Router inside Cellrenderer method with Ag-grid.

Example

```
cellRenderer: function (params) {
  return '<Link to="/customer/view/'+params.value+'">'+params.value+'</Link>'
}
```

I tried to use `reactNext=true` in the `ag-grid` props but no hope

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`frameworkComponents`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#react-cell-rendering) instead.

**Cell Renderer**

```js
const LinkCellRenderer = (params) => (
  <Link to={"/edit/" + params.data.id}>Edit</Link>
);
```

**Column Definitions**

```js
{
  headerName: "Action",
  field: "action",
  cellRenderer: "LinkCellRenderer"
}
```

**Component**

```js
<AgGridReact
  {...}
  frameworkComponents={{
    LinkCellRenderer
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64017685/cellrenderer-and-react-router-dom-link/]

Comment: you saved me hours of working, thank you @NearHuscarl